# How to turn multiple variables in a python list into a single variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables

I'm not quite sure how to go about mashing multiple variables of a list as one single variable, for example if I start started with something like:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4] # so numbers = [1,2,3,4]
```

How could I manage to get this as my output `newnumber[1234]`

Comment: Are you missing some equal signs? Your question is unclear. Please read [ask].

Comment: First, trying writing down a detailed description of how the first list is turned into the second value (is it a list?). Then, turn that into Python code, then test it.

Comment: You haven't defined clearly enough what you mean by "mashing"; that's not a technical term.  If you mean that you need to concatenate their representations ... well, where do you have a concatenation operator?  Alternately, what arithmetic produces the required result?  "I'm not quite sure how to go about" is not a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Its easy to understand what he means by "mashing" when you look at the output he desires: from `[1,2,3,4]` to `[1234]` He wants all the numbers to be together, not separated by commas.

Not sure if Im the only person who takes it that way. 

I understand this isn't detailed but when you say its not clear, I find that some what odd.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers=[1, 2, 3, 4]
newnumber=int(''.join(map(str,numbers))) #1234
```

Comment: alternatively:  `newnumber=sum([(n * (10 ** (len(numbers)-i-1))) for i,n in enumerate(numbers)])`

Comment: @aloisdg much fancier solution. Liked it :)